# How to fetch data from two table?

Tags: sql

I have two tables `Table1` & `Table2`

Table1

```
s.no|uniqueNumber | assigned_to
1.  | S123        | Tom
2.  | S234        | Harry
3.  | S345        | Tom
```

Table2

```
s.no|uniqueNumber | status
1.  | S123        | approve
2.  | S234        | approve
3.  | S345        | reject
```

I want to fetch `uniqueNumber` whose `status` is `approve` & `assigned` to `Tom`. I am trying to use `UNION` with `where` clause. But I think `UNION` doesn't work here. How to achieve this?

Comment: Show what you have tried. Union is not the right one, just do a normal join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a join:

```
select table1.uniqueNumber, status, assigned_to
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.uniqueNumber = table2.uniqueNumber
where status = 'approve' and assigned_to ='Tom'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
SELECT    t1.uniquenumber
FROM      table1 AS t1
JOIN      table2 AS t2
ON        t1.uniquenumber = t2.uniquenumber
WHERE     t2.status = 'approve'
AND       t1.assigned_to = 'Tom'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Subquery like...

```
select table1.uniqueNumber from table1 where assigned_to='Tom' 
       and table1.uniqueNumber 
       in  (
             select table2.uniqueNumber from  table2 where 
             status='approve'          
            );
```

OR..

you can directly join both tables..

```
select table1.uniqueNumber
       from table1 join table2 
         on table1.uniqueNumber = table2.uniqueNumber
         where status = 'approve' and assigned_to ='Tom'
```